# passing arguments in the URL on POST method

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to pass arguments in the URL

example:

```
// client side
URL: index.pl?action=view_user
METHOD: GET

#perl side

my $Q = CGI->new;
print $Q->param('action');
```

return me `view_user` but when try post by example on a form:

```
// client side
URL: index.pl?action=save_user
METHOD: POST
FORM:
   username: test

#perl side

my $Q = CGI->new;
print $Q->param('action'), "-", $Q->param('username');
```

return me `-test`. **why the param on url is blank?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `->url_param` instead of `->param` to get parameters from the URL when handling a POST request.